# populate text boxes on Access report from text boxes on form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to populate all the text boxes on the report with the data from the text boxes from a form. The names of the text boxes are the same on the form and on the report.
I tried this, but I'm stuck:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        ctl.ControlSource = "[Forms]![frmlisteannuelle]![ctl.name]"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why use VBA? Why not just set ControlSource in report design? Is data in table? Is form bound? Are controls bound? Why not use same table, query, or SQL statement in report RecordSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost there! It was just missing an equal sign at the start and a concatenation between the expression and the `clt.Name` value. Take a look:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            ctl.ControlSource = "=Forms![frmlisteannuelle]![" & ctl.Name & "]"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much, Ricardo! I spent hours on it and I didn't get the idea of the double equal sign and the concatenation. great, I can move on !

Comment: @user17404720, you're welcome! Please don't forget to pick one answer as accepted, so other users know you question was answered. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set ControlSource property with reference to form control name by using report control name, concatenate the variable and include = sign. Consider:

`ctl.ControlSource = "=[Forms]![frmlisteannuelle]![" & ctl.name & "]"`

Comment: You guys are just great! Same answer as Ricardo, thank you as well!

Comment: If answers resolved issue, please pick one as accepted. Can also upvote any or all.